# Serving Swagger UI and editor using Docker Compose and Traefik

Tags: docker-compose, swagger-ui, traefik, swagger-editor

My first attempt to start and use Swagger UI and Swagger Editor in the same time.
My approach is to define two services using Docker Compose and hiding them behind a reverse proxy, in this case Traefik.

But, something is wrong with my compose file and I can't figure out.

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.5
    restart: always
    command:
      - --accesslog
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
  swaggerui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PORT=8081
    expose:
      - 8081
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.swaggerui.rule=Host(`swaggerui`) && Path(`/ui`)
  swaggereditor:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-editor
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PORT=8082
    expose:
      - 8082
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.swaggereditor.rule=Host(`swaggereditor`) && Path(`/editor`)
```

Any suggestion?

KI

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify named entrypoint address (actually port number in container) in Traefik configuration at first

```
command:
  ...
  - "--entrypoints.swaggerui.address=:8081"
```

At the second step you should add label for **swaggerui** container, just like this

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.swaggerui.entrypoints=swaggerui"
  ...
```

After the above steps, everything should work